# android development View.OnClickListener error

Tags: java, android

I'm starting learning android development but im facing a an error which says :
    Multiple markers at this line
        - view cannot be resolved to a type
        - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable
    for the arguments (new 
     OnClickListener(){})
my program is :

```
package com.sc.uploader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add;
Button sub;
TextView disply;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    counter = 0;
    add =(Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);
    sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub);
    disply= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

so please if you could help me resolving the error i will be grateful

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
add.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {
```

to

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

capital "V". It is looking for a variable `view` when it should be set on the `View Class`.

[OnClickListener Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Comment: @user2887820 Most welcome! Please accept, when time allows, as the correct answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer if it solved your problem.